# (ptr + n-1) & -n what does this expression do?

Tags: c++, opencv

When I browsing c++ header files of opencv, It happened to see the construct `(ptr + n-1) & -n` in `alignPtr` function. The complete function as follows

```
/*!
  Aligns pointer by the certain number of bytes

  This small inline function aligns the pointer by the certain number of bytes by shifting
  it forward by 0 or a positive offset.
*/
template<typename _Tp> static inline _Tp* alignPtr(_Tp* ptr, int n=(int)sizeof(_Tp))
{
    return (_Tp*)(((size_t)ptr + n-1) & -n);
}
```

Can you explain how it works?

Comment: This small inline function aligns the pointer by the certain number of bytes by shifting it forward by 0 or a positive offset.

Comment: @erip this is very funny indeed, though the question is quote, "how it works", end of quote.

Comment: @bereal I noticed it after posting. I'm not funny.

Comment: you can find out by looking at what happens with the bit patterns when doing this calculation. Note that you'll need `n` to be a power of 2 for this to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to fully explain how binary and two-complement's arithmetic works, in a short answer to stackoverflow.com. Go buy an introductory book on computer programming, which should explain this in detail. That's the best answer for you.

Comment: This function is very poor, since it will fail for `n` not a power of two, which may easily happen for some types `_Tp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this expression its implicit that `n` is a power of `2` such as `2`, `4`, `8` etc.  Lets say that `n` is `2^m`

In a twos complement binary system:

- `-2` is ...11110
- `-4` is ...11100
- `-8` is ...11000

In general, `n = -2^m` has a representation with exactly the `m` rightmost digits being zero.

This means, if we take any number and `&` it with `-2^m` then it will be returned with the `m` rightmost digits being zero, and the other digits retained, which makes the answer **a multiple of `2^m`**.

This means the expression `x & -2^m` will effectively "floor" the number to the largest multiple of `2^m` that is less than or equal to `x`.

The addition of `(n - 1)` that is being done:

```
(x + (n-1)) & -2^m
```

effectively changes this from a "floor" to a "rounding".